# How to save the radio button selection in database using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

This is my controller:

```
class ReportNeedsController < ApplicationController
def index
@report_needs = nil
end
  def new
     @report_need = ReportNeed.new
  end    
  def create
     @report_need = ReportNeed.new(params[:report_need])
     @report_need.save
     redirect_to @report_need
  end
end
```

This is my new.haml file:

Why do you want to report?

```
%form
    %input{:name => "option", :type => "radio", :value => "spam"}
    spam                   
    %br/    

enter code here


    %input{:name => "option", :type => "radio", :value => "product_corrupted"}      
    product_corrupted                   
    %br/                      
    %input{:name => "option", :type => "radio", :value => "product_spoiled"}       
    product_spoiled
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in view like :

```
  %input{:type => "radio", :name => "report_need[product_type]", :id => "report_need[product_type]-1", :value => "salesforce", :checked => true}
  %br/
  %input{:type => "radio", :name => "report_need[product_type]", :id => "report_need[product_type]-2", :value => "salesforce", }
```

In controller, If **product_type** is field of table **report_needs** then no need to change in your action . else its change and store it like :

```
  def create
     report_need = ReportNeed.new(params[:report_need])
     report_need.radio_field_name = params[:report_need][product_type]
     report_need.save
     redirect_to report_need
  end
```